# Website JS scripts not loading on first load, reloading fix it. Never works on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, prestashop

this is my first time asking a question through stackoverflow, while I've been a reader for years. It's the first time I really couldn't find an answer to my problem through the search function and it is probably because it's specific to my website.

I don't know when or after which modification I did, some javascript modules started behaving weird. The website would load partially the first time you visit it on chrome and then will load correctly if you refresh the browser. This won't happen on Firefox where the website will always be uncomplete. All javascript modules aren't loading correctly.

Website URL: www.levicechocolat.com

What I've tried so far:

- Disabling Prestashop's Smart Caché for JavaScript features. This fixed 1 script, the navigation hover menu so I'll keep it off.
- Disable CSS Smart Caché didn't fix anything, I kept it on. Same for all other prestashop optimizing features, tried one by one enabling/disabling and the only change I noticed was the above mentioned so that's the unique PS optimizing feature I kept off. I'll keep HTML compression off till I solve this issue.
- Read that putting JS code at the end just before the `</body>` tag may fix this problem but it didn't.

I'd really appreciate if you can help me to figure this out. If you need me to post a code just let me know and I will.

Thank you very much for your help. If you live in Chile or come to Chile and you help me out I'd be glad to offer you some chocolates :).

Comment: Please tell us the versions of browser in which you are testing it ?

Comment: Works for me on Chrome and IE11 on Windows 7. Breaks in Firefox though. Have you tried turning off the Tawk.to module? Firefox console show's "ReferenceError: writeCookie is not defined" at line 357, column 1255.... not sure, but might be because the writeCookie() function is only being defined after it's called.

Comment: I'm using latest version of Chrome (44.0.2403.125 (64-bit)) and Firefox (39). I also tried to disable tawk.to module, sumome module, etc. Regarding that writeCookie function I saw it before at the console but I didn't give it too much importance, I'll try to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably there are some issues with the theme or some modules installed.

On Chrome it's working correctly for me and I see no Javascript errors. The wierdness is happening on Firefox, the homepage is not loading correctly and in developer console I see this javascript error: ReferenceError: writeCookie is not defined

You definetly need to debug this. What I recommend doing is moving your store on a local development machine and do the following:

- Activate Prestashop's development mode: edit config/defines.inc.php at line 29 change: define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false); to true: define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
- From Back Office > Advanced Parameters > Performance disable all CCC (COMBINE, COMPRESS AND CACHE) options - mainly "Move JavaScript to the end" and "Compress inline JavaScript in HTML" give errors on some themes
- If it's still not working right (check for errors on Firefox and Chrome) and no other javascript errors show up try to "Disable non PrestaShop modules" from Advanced Parameters > Performance > DEBUG MODE

You can also have a look at the theme's custom javascript code maybe you can spot something there.

I hope this sheds some light on your issues.

Comment: Thank you, this will take some time, I'll do it this evening and let you know my progress.

Comment: I finally solved it by doing what you mentioned! Disabling all modules was fixing the issue so I disabled custom modules one by one till I found THE module. For your reference, it was Retina Images by TreeTheme.

Answer (score 0):

it might be an issue with http and https.

Browsers might complain or don't load at all if resources are coming from mixed sources (secured and unsecured).

If your site is unsecured (http), try loading only resources (scripts, images) from unsecured sources.

If you cannot avoid loading resources from secured sources (https), you should consider get a SSL certificate and secure your website.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I believe that the only https module I have is Tawk.to and disabling it doesn't fix the problem :(